# Passing values from comma seperated string and assigning to different variables in korn shell

Tags: sql, shell, teradata, ksh

I'm exporting the result from a SQL query as comma separated string to a variable. How to assign each value from the string to a variable name and export.

```
$SQLOUTPUT_STRING=1,2018-05-16,abc,123
```

I want to assign the values from above string to variables and export them

```
export VAR1=1
export VAR2=2018-05-16
export VAR3=abc
export VAR4=123
```

I'm using these variables in other scripts so I cannot names these generic as above, so VAR1,VAR2,VAR3,VAR4 wont be the case, it would be different names.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What errors have you gotten or problems have you run into?  It will be easier to help if you include your code.  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this again ... assuming no commas embedded in your data, you could use a variation of the `read` command to split the string into your list of variables.

To show this solution handles embedded white space we'll start with a modified version of your sample string:

```
$ input="1,2018-05-16,abc def,asdf 123"
```

We'll now tell `read` to use a comma as the input field separator (IFS), and we'll use a here-string to pass `${input}` to `read`, which gives us:

```
$ IFS=, read -r VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4 <<< "${input}"

$ echo "${VAR1}"
1

$ echo "${VAR2}"
2018-05-16

$ echo "${VAR3}"
abc def

$ echo "${VAR4}"
asdf 123
```

This should be a bit faster than my previous answer (below) based on parameter substitution *plus* you don't destroy the contents of `${input}`.

Here's a [bash fiddle](http://tpcg.io/KzPycd) for the above solution, and a [ksh93 fiddle](http://tpcg.io/EydDvE) showing the same solution.

---

My previous answer/ramblings ...

If you can work with arrays, run a search on "bash split string into array" and you should get several SO hits to help you out.

If you absolutely, positively need to use individual variables, I'd probably use parameter substitution to strip out the fields.

```
${variable%%,*}      # strip off the first field of a comma-delimited string
${variable#*,}       # strip off fields 2-n of a comma-delimeted string
```

Applying this to your example string we get:

```
$ input="1,2018-05-16,abc,123"

$ VAR1="${input%%,*}"    input="${input#*,}"
$ VAR2="${input%%,*}"    input="${input#*,}"
$ VAR3="${input%%,*}"    input="${input#*,}"
$ VAR4="${input%%,*}"    input="${input#*,}"

$ echo "${VAR1}"
1

$ echo "${VAR2}"
2018-05-16

$ echo "${VAR3}"
abc

$ echo "${VAR4}"
123
```

- each successive `VAR= / input=` pair places the leading field into `VAR` and updates`input` to contain the remaining fields
- if you need to retain the original value in `input` then start off by copying `input` into another variable that you can break apart

While this may look like a bit more programming than, say, using `cut` or `awk` to strip out fields, the key benefit is that you don't need to spawn a new sub-process (like you do for `cut` and `awk` solutions) so you should find that performance is improved (and the performance improvement should be quite noticeable for large volumes of input string processing).

Obviously (?) this could get a tad more complicated if you're dealing with data that a) contains commas, b) spans multiple lines and/or c) contains non-printing/control characters ...

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, I have used array and case to do this but I think I will replace it with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cut` command in shell scripts to grab individual fields or whole columns of a CSV file, one per invocation of the `cut` command. `cut` expects the input CSV data to be supplied via standard input, so you could use the "here" document shell feature to present the contents of your `SQLOUTPUT_STRING` shell variable as stdin.

The following sequence of commands will assign the values `1`, `2018-05-16`, `abc`, and `123` to `VAR1` through `VAR2`, respectively:

```
SQLOUTPUT_STRING=1,2018-05-16,abc,123

export VAR1=`cut -d, -f1 <<
$SQLOUTPUT_STRING
EOF
`
export VAR2=`cut -d, -f2 <<
$SQLOUTPUT_STRING
EOF
`
export VAR3=`cut -d, -f3 <<
$SQLOUTPUT_STRING
EOF
`
export VAR4=`cut -d, -f4 <<
$SQLOUTPUT_STRING
EOF
`
```

Note I've used traditional Bourne shell backtick escapes to make the shell execute the command enclosed in backticks and use its output as literal replacement value to expand in-place in the `export` statement since you specifically requested portable shell code. There might exist alternative syntax and redirection operators in modern ksh shell syntax.